# Prove that such number $C$ exists..

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The task is to prove that for sequences $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ A_n \}$ for which the following is right: $a_n-(A_n-A_{n-1})=c_n$, where series $\sum c_n $ is converging do exist such number $C$, that $a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n=A_n+C+O(1)$ (O(1) - O-notation here).

Came across this one during my prepartion for an exam I'm taking in a week. May you help with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum from $1 $ to $N$ on both sides. Using the telescopic sum you get $\sum_{n=1}^N A_n-A_{n-1}=A_N-A_0$, hence:$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n-A_N+A_0=\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n$$ so that $a_1+...a_N=A_N+O(1)$, where $O(1)=-A_0+\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n$ (it is $O(1)$ since it is a constant plus a converging, hence bounded, sequence)

Comment: And why there is sum from 1 to N in your O(1)?

Comment: A typo I've corrected